# Acces rights when writing a folder

Tags: c#, security, directory

When writing a file in a directory like: 
`C:\ProgramData\Something\Somthingmore` 
i get an `UnauthorizedAccesException`. how can i make sure that i can always write to there? my application needs to write loggfiles,  (the `Environment.SpecialFolder` does exacly the same thing.) but i do not want to write data there, i need all users to write and read data from the folder and subfolders. i have tried to modify my app.manifest to: 
`<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`
 but this did not help either, also setting the `UAC` to either  lowest or highest did not make any diference.

When i use Envireoment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData i get this exception:
`UnauthorizedAccesException`

Acces to path C:\Users\PC2\AppData\Roaming\AppName\Logging\SubFolder is denied.

Comment: That's a *really* bad place for log files.  c:\programdata is write-protected, use appdata instead.  Or use an installer that changes the ACL of the subdirectory.  If you don't see the UAC prompt after you modified the manifest then turn of the VS hosting process, a quirk in VS2013.

Comment: what makes your program to write logs or else in such windows directory ? is it desktop application ? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Hans Passant. Is there any folder you would recomend using when writing loggfiles that all users can read and write, to logg my files?

Comment: There are not a lot of operating systems left that allow users that are not administrators to destroy each other's data files.  Windows is not an exception of course.  You can change the rule, you have to do so explicitly by changing the accessibility of the shared folder so Everybody can write to it.

Comment: Hmm that makes sense, but even if i write to a folder that is not shared, i get the same exception, i have tried alot of folders(desktop, documents, c:\, appData), created subfolders in it and try to write a file to it, and every time i get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Default permissions on those folders can be tricky. By default, they are restricted. Opening up their security is something to be done during setup, if any, or you'll need to require an administrator to configure manually.

This is alluded to in the comments here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2008/02/05/where-should-i-write-program-data-instead-of-program-files.aspx